# What does すがすがしいな mean?

Tags: usage, manga

I am reading Yotsuba&! manga Ch.82, Pg.12 ([source](http://raw.senmanga.com/Yotsubato!/82/12)) [image]

What does the last bubble on the lower left side (おまえすがすがしいな) mean? What does すがすがしいな mean in this context?

Dictionary meaning is

> refreshing; brisk; bracing; fresh; refreshed ([source](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%84))

How is the dictionary meaning used in the above context? Is there some other meaning to すがすがしい?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(却って/むしろ)すがすがしい(ほどの) is often used sarcastically, preceding a bad expression. It means something is so typically bad that it almost feels good.

- すがすがしい(ほどの)嘘: an obvious lie which almost sounds like a joke
- すがすがしい(ほどの)変態: a 100% pervert without reservation who is even almost admirable
- すがすがしい(ほどの)馬鹿: a "perfect" idiot

The guy said お前すがすがしいな because Yotsuba's line was so typically selfish that it even sounded funny instead of irritating.

Comment: Would your first sentence translate to something like lie of a refreshing degree ? な in [お前すがすがしいな] is something like a masculine form of ね right ? I thought it was ending な saying not to do something which doesn't make much sense now that I think. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if "lie of a refreshing degree" is a common English expression. The な at the end is a sentence-end particle like ね. な that means "Don't" does not directly attach to adjectives (you cannot say "don't shy", can you?)

Answer (score 4):

「すがすがしい」, in this context, is used just a little bit sarcastically to refer to the girl's unreserved manner of speech.

My best TL for 「おまえすがすがしいな」 would be:

> "You don't beat around the bush, do you?"

Answer (score 2):

I've just found this site and I agree to the first noter.

すがすがしい has at least two meanings - one is what you wrote and the other is "without hesitation when you change their mind in the way that people normally hesitate to do, thinking about people's reaction."

I hope this will help.